# XML file sort particular nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, xpath, nodes

I am not very good with xsl, but I would like to sort the following xml:

```
<Parent>
        <node1/>
        <class>b</class>

        <class>c</class>


         <node2/> 
        <class>a</class>
</Parent>
```

into the following so that only the class elements are sorted and other elements are untouched:

```
<Parent>
        <node1/>
        <class>a</class>
        <class>b</class>
        <class>c</class>
        <node2/>        
</Parent>
```

I am using the following xsl within a java code to transform my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="class">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" >
    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="class" />

    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this gives me :

```
<Parent>
    <node1/>
    <class/>
    <class/>
    <node2/>
    <class/>
</Parent>
```

Comment: In your sample in output XML `a` is between `node1` and `node2`, although in initial XML `a` is under `node2`. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct..I wanted all the other nodes to be in their own places but bring the class nodes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="class[1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="//class">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="class"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Parent>
  <node1 />
  <class>a</class>
  <class>b</class>
  <class>c</class>
  <node2 />
</Parent>
```